# Create a Multidimensional Array based on priority in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to convert this input array into a multidimensional array in PHP. Depending on the priority value child will be append.

**Input Data:**

```
$input = [
    ['content' => 'Level One', 'priority' => 1],
    ['content' => 'Level Two', 'priority' => 2],
    ['content' => 'Level Six', 'priority' => 6],
    ['content' => 'Level Two', 'priority' => 2],
    ['content' => 'Level One', 'priority' => 1],
    ['content' => 'Level Six', 'priority' => 6],
];
```

**Output:**

```
$output = [
    [
        'content' => 'Level One', 
        'priority' => 1,
        'child' => [
            [
                'content' => 'Level Two', 
                'priority' => 2,
                'child' => [
                    [
                        'content' => 'Level Six', 
                        'priority' => 6,
                        'child' => []
                    ],
                ]
            ],
            [
                'content' => 'Level Two', 
                'priority' => 2,
                'child' => []
            ],
        ]
    ],
    [
        'content' => 'Level One', 
        'priority' => 1,
        'child' => [
            [
                'content' => 'Level Six', 
                'priority' => 6,
                'child' => []
            ],
        ]
    ]
];
```

Multidimensional is not working here. In case anyone is interested, I'm doing this code, but failed. I do not understand, how the Multidimensional loop is working.

```
$formatted = array_reduce($input, function($output, $item) {
    $node = [];
    if (count($output) > 0 && $item['priority'] !== 1) {
        $node = $output;
        $index = $item['priority'];
        while ($index > 1) {
            if (isset($node[$index - 1]['child'])) {
                $item['child'] = [];
                $node[] = $item;
            }
            $index--;
        }
    } else {
        $item['child'] = [];
        $output[] = $item;
    }
    return $output;
}, []);

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $formatted );
echo '</pre>';
```